# Incorrect HTML when pre-populating nested forms in Rails 5.1

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have a Rails 5.1 app that consumes the Google Books API and I need to pre-populate nested fields in a form. There are two ways to create a `Book`.

Firstly, through the normal `/books/new` form, which `accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors` with a `has_many: through` association. Here I am using `cocoon` gem and everything is working great.

Secondly, a user can create a `Book` by searching the Google Books API using an ISBN number. This data then pre-populates a form before being submitted to the `create` action in the `BooksController`. I have managed to get this working great apart from the ability to correctly submit the nested `Author` data.

I currently have each author populate a field in the form, yet when I come to submit the data only the last item in the author array (in the case of a book with multiple authors) gets saved.

I believe this is because the form html has the same `name` and `id` for both fields as below. How do I get this form to submit both authors?

```
<input value="John J. Ratey" type="text" name="book[authors_attributes][0][name]" id="book_authors_attributes_0_name">
<input value="Richard Manning" type="text" name="book[authors_attributes][0][name]" id="book_authors_attributes_0_name">
```

`books_controller.rb`

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_book, except: [:index, :new, :create, :new_book, :submit_book]

def create
    @book = current_user.books.create(book_params)
    @book.authors.each {|author| author.user_id = current_user.id}

    if @book.save
        redirect_to book_path(@book)
    else
        render :new
    end
end

def new_book
end

def submit_book
    @book = Book.new
    @book.authors.new
    @response = GoogleBooks.new(params[:q], @book)
end

private

    def set_book
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    def book_params
        params.require(:book).permit(:title, :subtitle, :description, author_ids:[], authors_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
    end

end
```

`book.rb`

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_authors
  has_many :authors, through: :book_authors

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors, allow_destroy: true

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates_associated :authors
end
```

`google_books.rb`

```
class GoogleBooks
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1'

  def initialize(isbn, book)
    @query = self.class.get("/volumes?q=isbn:#{isbn}")
    @book = book
  end

  def title
    @query['items'].first['volumeInfo']['title']
  end

  def subtitle
    @query['items'].first['volumeInfo']['subtitle']
  end

  def description
    @query['items'].first['volumeInfo']['description']
  end

  def authors
    @query['items'].first['volumeInfo']['authors']
    #=> ['John J. Ratey', 'Richard Manning']
  end

end
```

`submit_book.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, value: @response.title %>
  <%= f.text_field :subtitle, value: @response.subtitle %>
  <%= f.text_field :description, value: @response.description %>

  <%= f.fields_for :authors, @book.authors.build do |authors_fields| %>
    <% @response.authors.each do |author| %>
      <%= authors_fields.text_field :name, value: author %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

<%= f.submit %>
```

Comment: Can you append [] to the id?

Comment: @Psi Can you elaborate on exactly what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out.

Was a case of changing

```
<%= f.fields_for :authors, @book.authors.build do |authors_fields| %>
  <% @response.authors.each do |author| %>
    <%= authors_fields.text_field :name, value: author %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

to this

```
<% @response.authors.each do |author| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :authors, @book.authors.build do |authors_fields| %>
    <%= authors_fields.text_field :name, value: author %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Which produces the following correct HTML:

```
<input value="John J. Ratey" type="text" name="book[authors_attributes][0][name]" id="book_authors_attributes_0_name">
<input value="Richard Manning" type="text" name="book[authors_attributes][1][name]" id="book_authors_attributes_1_name">
```